# JList Selection bugging out when using another Jlist Selection

Tags: java

I have an interface where i select classes, each class gives multiples relations between her and the other classes, when you click on the relation it gives you the details.

Everything works fine, but as soon as i click a relation to show detail, and then try to move to another class the relation listmodel doesn't update and the selection in the jlist class start picking multiple at once and bugging out even if i specified single selection mode.What is the reason for this?

```
listClasses.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
listRelations.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
listClasses.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {
                relationsModel.removeAllElements(); 
                if (!arg0.getValueIsAdjusting()) {//This line prevents double events

                    detailsModel.removeAllElements();
                    relationsModel.removeAllElements(); 
                    HashSet<Relation> relations;    
                    if(relations.size()==0) { 
                        relationsModel.removeAllElements(); 
                    }else{
                        relationsModel.removeAllElements(); 
                    for(Relation myRelation : relations) {
                        relationsModel.addElement(myRelation) ;
                        }
                    }}

                }

            }
        });
```

The details show on click of the relations. I tried to put the removeall in multiple places but in vein.

```
listRelations.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {

                if (!arg0.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                    detailsModel.removeAllElements();
detailsModel.addElement(listRelations.getSelectedValue()).getDetail()); 
                }
            }
        });
```